# Nhibernate associate entity already saved in the database with a new item in a joined-subclass

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, joined-subclass

The situation is as follows:
I own a table called "Entidade" in the database, and a table "Medico". The table "Medico" is a joined-subclass entity in the table as below:

```
<joined-subclass name="Medico" table="Medico">
  <key column="SEQ_ENTIDADE"/>
  <property name="DSC_CRM"/>
  <property name="DSC_ESPECIALIDADE"/>
  <property name="FLG_SEXO"/>
</joined-subclass>
```

The user should be able to use an "Entidade" already registered to "Turn it" on a "Medico". When I try to save the object "Medico" that extends the class "Entidade" with the same ID "Entidade" has saved the following error occurs:

```
violation of PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY constraint "PK_ENTIDADE" on table "ENTIDADE"
```

My class "Medico":

```
public class Medico : Entidade
{
    public virtual string DSC_CRM { get; set; }

    public virtual string DSC_ESPECIALIDADE { get; set; }

    public virtual Sexo FLG_SEXO { get; set; }
}
```

There is the possibility of making this "Transformation"?

Should you need anything else to understand the situation just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a subclass should not be used in your case. That is not a question of nHibernate but to classes and inheritance.

If you have additional properties for your instance that can be added or removed over time I would not use inheritance for your model but aggregation. And then your joined subclass problem will become a reference problem (or HasMany) and you are fine.

Regards,
Michael